# Flutter how can i go deeper in the json file

Tags: json, flutter, api, http, dart

I want to go deeper in the JSON File how what i need to change in the code.

because i need to go deeper in data -> resources-> items-> title

```
My JSON:

{
   "status":"UPDATE",
   "data":{
  "version":"2",
  "modDate":"2021-12-22T17:33:59+0100",
  "languages":[
     "DE",
     "EN"
  ],
  "mapmarker":[
     
  ],
  "resources":[
     {
        "id":241,
        "type":"image",
        "items":[
           {
              "lang":"DE",
              "title":"Labor",
              "file":"uploads\/",
              "size":1923217,
              "modDate":"2019-02-28T18:07:46+0100"
           },
           {
              "lang":"EN",
              "title":"Faust Labor",
              "file":"uploads\/",
              "size":1923217,
              "modDate":"2019-02-28T18:07:46+0100"
           }
        ]
     },
```

MY Not working Code actual:

```
Future<void> getDaten() async {
final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse("https://blabla"));

  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

  var deviceData = extractedData["data"] as Map<String, dynamic>;

  var deviceData2 = deviceData["resources"] as Map<String, dynamic>;

  deviceData["items"].forEach((e)=>print(e["text"]));


}
```

My existing Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
```

I can go only to data -> resources -> items and then i only get Strings like this

```
[{lang: DE, title: Schmuck, Uhren und Spiele, file: uploads/Spiele.JPG, size: 774265, modDate: 2021-12-13T16:04:25+0100}]
```

Comment: Please note that you problem is that `resources` does not return `Map<String, dynamic>` but `List<dynamic>` where each element is `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want to extract all `titles` across all items in resources. Please note that we don't need to cast every single value we are using since `dynamic` means that Dart should just ignore what we are doing with the object and expect any call on `dynamic` to also be `dynamic`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  dynamic jsonObject = jsonDecode(jsonString);

  final titles = [
    for (Map<String, dynamic> resource in jsonObject['data']['resources'])
      for (Map<String, dynamic> item in resource['items'])
        item['title'] as String
  ];

  titles.forEach(print);
  // Labor
  // Faust Labor
}

const jsonString = '''{
  "status": "UPDATE",
  "data": {
    "version": "2",
    "modDate": "2021-12-22T17:33:59+0100",
    "languages": [
      "DE",
      "EN"
    ],
    "mapmarker": [
    ],
    "resources": [
      {
        "id": 241,
        "type": "image",
        "items": [
          {
            "lang": "DE",
            "title": "Labor",
            "file": "uploads\/",
            "size": 1923217,
            "modDate": "2019-02-28T18:07:46+0100"
          },
          {
            "lang": "EN",
            "title": "Faust Labor",
            "file": "uploads\/",
            "size": 1923217,
            "modDate": "2019-02-28T18:07:46+0100"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
''';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function below lines

```
  var deviceData = extractedData["data"] as Map<String, dynamic>;

  var deviceData2 = deviceData["resources"] as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Are causing error because in your API `extractedData["data"]` is `returning` you a `List` but you are casting it as `Map<String, dynamic>` that's why it's throwing an error. To solve this use like this :

```
  var deviceData = extractedData["data"];

  var deviceData2 = deviceData["resources"];
```